# Angular 4 and ngForm - unselected radio button options are being submitted

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel

I have a simple quiz with a set of questions and with each question having 4-5 multichoice options. The correct option is selected by clicking an associated radio button.

When I submit the form, the selected options are sent to the server, BUT so too is the last option of every unanswered question.

The template/code to create the quiz is:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" class="form-horizontal">                    
   <div *ngFor="let item of aData; let i=index">
     <p class="question"><strong>Question {{i+1}}.</strong>  <span [innerHTML]="item['question'] | keepHtml"></span></p>
     <ul class="nobullet">
       <li class='mcqoptions' *ngFor="let mcq of item.mcq">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="option{{i}}" [ngModel]="mcq['mcqID']" value="{{mcq['mcqID']}}" ><span [innerHTML]="mcq['mcqoption'] | keepHtml"></span>
          </label>
       </li>
     </ul>
      <p id="qfb{{item['questionID']}}" class="quizfback"></p>
      <input  type="hidden" name="questionID{{i}}" [ngModel]="item['questionID']"/>
    </div>
    <div style="padding:20px 0" class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit this quiz</button>
      </div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

The submit function is:

```
onSubmit(f):void{    
const dataToSave = f.value;
this.service.processQuiz('processquiz', dataToSave).subscribe(
  fback => {
    this.submitPending = false;                 
    this.msg = fback.msg;
    this.bMessage = true;
  }, error => {
    this.submitPending = false;
  }, () => {
    this.submitPending = false;
  } 
);
```

I'm missing something here but I can't find it.

Thanks/Tom

Comment: Is the default value set to null for every option and why not change value to [value] = mcq['mcqID']

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I don't understand either point. How is the default value set to null? This isn't explicitly done in a 'normal' HTML form. How is it explicitly done in a form within Angular?

Comment: [ngModel]="mcq['mcqID']" value="{{mcq['mcqID']}}"  should not be the same according to my understanding you are always selecting the value and the fact that its always the last is because radio selects only one value so last one stays as your selected value for the question that are unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

First please show the rest of the code for the component.

Second, you are already pre-setting the value to each radio button before the user selects, so even if they don't make a selection there is already a value that will be sent `onSubmit`. `value="{{mcq['mcqID']}}"`

```
<input type="radio" name="option{{i}}" [ngModel]="mcq['mcqID']" value="{{mcq['mcqID']}}" ><span [innerHTML]="mcq['mcqoption'] | keepHtml"></span>
```